# In Google Map's JS API fromPointToLatLng doesn't seem accurate based on events

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My goal is when they have a drawing tool like the rectangle tool, if they single click somewhere it centers the map where they clicked as to make it easier for them to draw their rectangle without needing to switch tools or drag to the window edge and have it scroll.

I cannot use Google Map's events because they disable them if you use their DrawingManager, so I'm forced to use jQuery or vanilla JS.

I have a map that is 100% wide and ~50% of the window height. Here's the basic code I've been trying everything I can think of on:

```
    $('#myMapWapperElement').on('click', function (event) {
        var position = settings.map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(
            new google.maps.Point(
                event.offsetX,
                event.offsetY
            )
        );
        map.setCenter(position);
    });
```

This, however, makes the map jump all over when I click. It doesn't center where the marker clicked at all. I tried offsetX, pageX, and also relative by offsetX - "elementPositionX". Nothing seems to center correctly.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fromPointToLatLng` and `fromLatLngToPoint` methods of [`google.maps.Projection` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Projection) translate between points in a `256x256` coordinate system and real world coordinates. You could utilize the following function to translate from pixel coordinates on a map projection to LatLng values:

```
var fromPixelToLatLng = function (map, x, y) {
    var projection = map.getProjection();
    var topRight = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
    var bottomLeft = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
    var scale = 1 << map.getZoom();
    return projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(x / scale + bottomLeft.x, y / scale + topRight.y));
};
```

**Example**

```js
function initMap() {
   
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
    });

  

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ''
    });


    $("#map").on('click', function (event) {
        var position = fromPixelToLatLng(map, event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
        infowindow.setContent('Pixel(' + event.offsetX + ',' + event.offsetY + ') -> LatLng:' + position.toString());
        infowindow.setPosition(position);
        infowindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(position);
    });

  

    //var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    //    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    //    drawingControl: true,
    //    drawingControlOptions: {
    //        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    //        drawingModes: [
    //          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    //          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    //          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    //          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
    //          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
    //        ]
    //    }
    //});
    //drawingManager.setMap(map);  
}


var fromPixelToLatLng = function (map, x, y) {
    var projection = map.getProjection();
    var topRight = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
    var bottomLeft = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
    var scale = 1 << map.getZoom();
    return projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(x / scale + bottomLeft.x, y / scale + topRight.y));
};
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .fromContainerPixelToLatLng of [MapCanvasProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapCanvasProjection)

That method is available on the OverlayView class.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ugwxrgqs/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {
    console.log("draw");
  };
  overlay.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'projection_changed', function() {
    var projection = overlay.getProjection();
    $('#map_canvas').on('click', function(event) {
      var position = projection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(
        new google.maps.Point(
          event.offsetX,
          event.offsetY
        )
      );
      map.setCenter(position);
    });
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```